# Website building tool for someone moving from FrontPage?

Tags: cms, static-site-generator

i'm helping a friend create a new website, he has a number of requirements:

- Ability to import the old site (html-based)

  - and keep all the permalinks as they are
- Multiple (15) parts of the website ("sub-site") - which looks like their own site - each with their own /directory/ (or maybe subdomain)
- Multiple people should be able to update the website (or a sub-site)
- Control over how the permalinks look
- Ideally wen want the website to run for a very long time (30 years or more), but if and when it fails he wants it to be easy to export and import the website into another system (again keeping the permalinks can be kept as they are)

Please note that my friend is not a nerd and wants something user-friendly!

The website that he currently has is built with FrontPage and does not implement the requirement "Multiple people should be able to update the website"

These are some of my own thoughts as to solutions:

- WordPress multisite
- 15 WordPress installations - one for each sub-site
- Single WordPress install with some access restrictions for different parts of the site (is this possible?) - what about making it look like there are different sub-sites?
- Drupal with access restrictions similar to the above
- Static html site like now but with a modern alternative to FrontPage (any recommendations?) - This may not implement the requirement "Multiple people should be able to update the website"
- Using a static site generator (any recommendations here? I've looked at Jekyll but it's not currently supported on Windows and i'm not sure if it's user-friendly enough) - This may not implement the requirement "Multiple people should be able to update the website" unless people use a version control system and also install the static site generator software on their computers

Grateful for help!

Kind Regards,
Tord